# jQuery not sliding correctly

Tags: jquery, html, dom

jQuery isn't sliding when the first checkbox is clicked. I believe it is the correct syntax, but I am not sure. I have looked at it in multiple browsers, even uploading it to a website. but all to no avail. What is wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>Test</title>
<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>                    </script>
   <script>$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#test1').click(function(){
       if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
       $('#test12').slideUp('fast');
       } else {
       $('#test12').slideDown('fast');
       }
   });
   });
   </script>

   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>form test</h1>
   <span><input id="test1" type="checkbox">Hello<br></span>
   <span><input id="test12" type="checkbox">Yo</span>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.prop('checked')` instead of `.attr()`

See the attributes vs. properties section here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Try this  (v1.6+)

```
if ($(this).attr('checked') == "checked")
```

(pre-1.6).. your condition **was** valid

```
if ($(this).attr('checked'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is incorrect. Try changing it to this.

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.change()`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PGPpC/

```
$('#test1').change(function(){
    $('#test12').slideToggle('fast');
});
```